# Obtain a special solution for a differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a differential equation $y" + 4y' + 4y = 2e^{-x} + xe^{-x}$ and $f(x)$ is a special solution to this equation, how can I determine $f(x)$ if I know f(0)=0 and $f'(0)=0$ ?

Comment: have you tried $y=e^{rt}$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja How do you mean?

Comment: It's just a way to solve those kind of ODE's. As you may see in the answer given. In her case she took $y=e^{\lambda x}$.

Comment: Oh yes, I wasn't thinking straight. I used $Ae^{-x} + Bxe^{-x}$ to obtain the $y_p$ part of the solution. Is that correct?

Comment: In this kind of problem, first find the solution to the homogeneous equation, later on you'll attempt to find what to make with the other side of the equation, in your case, $2e^{-x} + xe^{-x}$. And finally use the initial problem values to determine the constants you'd found. You shoud take a look at Boyce-Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems 10th Theorem 3.5.1 and 3.5.2.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. It helped a lot. Going by that, $y_c$ is correct, and I believe the $y_p$ that I have assumed is also correct because it is not related to the complementary solution. Am I right? And after that I can proceed to solve for $f(x)$ using $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

First, solve the homogeneous problem: $$ y'' + 4y' + 4y =0 $$ as followed:

The characteristic equation is:
$$\lambda^2+4 \lambda+4=0 \Rightarrow (\lambda+2)^2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=-2$$

Therefore, the solution of the homogeneous problem is:

$$y_h(x)=c_1 e^{\lambda_1 x}+c_2 x e^{\lambda_2 x}=c_1 e^{-2x}+c_2 xe^{-2x}$$

Then to find the patial solution by solving the non-homogeneous problem we consider the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ as function in respect of $x$, $c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$.

$$y_p(x)=c_1 (x) e^{-2x}+c_2 (x) xe^{-2x}$$

Calculate the derivatives $y_p'(x)$ and $y_p''(x)$ and replace these at the initial problem, to find the functions $c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$.

Finally, the solution of the problem $$y'' + 4y' + 4y = 2e^{-x} + xe^{-x}$$ 
is equal to $$f(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$$

Now, use the two initial values $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ to calculate the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Isn't this the procedure to find the general solution to the equation? And if it is, I used $Ae^{-x} + Bxe^{-x}$ as $y_p$ for the general solution, where $A$ and $B$ are constants. Is that correct?